# sed next & Next command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Wonder if someone can explain the difference between Next (N) and the next(n) command in sed. i was trying following.

this is my input file

```
Consult Section 3.1 in the Owner and Operator Guide
Consult Section 3.1 in the Owner and Operator Guide
for a description of the tape drives
available on your system.
```

i was using following (next command)

```
/Operator/{
n
s/Owner and Operator Guide/Installation Guide/
}
```

result is

```
Consult Section 3.1 in the Owner and Operator Guide
Consult Section 3.1 in the Installation Guide
for a description of the tape drives
available on your system.
```

then i was using following

```
 /Operator/{
 N
 s/Owner and Operator Guide/Installation Guide/
 }
```

result is

```
Consult Section 3.1 in the Installation Guide
Consult Section 3.1 in the Owner and Operator Guide
for a description of the tape drives
available on your system.
```

can you please explain why I'm getting two different results ? do i need to use Next command (N) only in multiline pattern space ? and where to use next (n) command.

If i use sed 's/Owner and Operator Guide/Installation Guide/' input.txt  will change everything as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` command prints out the pattern space (unless the "-n" flag is used), clears the pattern space, and reads in the next line. In your example,

```
/Operator/{
n
s/Owner and Operator Guide/Installation Guide/
}
```

￼`/Operator/` is matched for the first line. After performing the `n` command, we print the pattern space so your first line is print as is. Second line is loaded in to pattern space and the substitution is performed. As a result, you see the changes on the second line.

The `N` command, unlike `n` command, does not print the current pattern space, and does not clear it. Instead it appends the next line to the pattern space separated by a newline. As a result your substitution is performed on the first line since you are not using a global flag.